# Magento: what does option "before" do in config.xml file?

Tags: magento

I added admin controller.
This code works correct:

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mycompany_mymodule>Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mycompany_mymodule >
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

If I add before="Mage_Adminhtml" to mycompany_mymodule:

```
<mycompany_mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mycompany_mymodule >
```

then it doesn't work - got 404 error.

**1. What does this option do?**

Also I looked throught Alans' Storm article: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers
There are example:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld</module>
                    <frontName>adminhelloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <!-- ... -->        
</config>
```

**2. What is the difference between these definitions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It solved:

I found `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` class where `collectRoutes()` method is defined. It parses "after" and "before" parameters to order the modules.

This method is calling from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin` (started from `init` method in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front`).

So after I looked through match process in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard`.

After `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` debuging I understood my fault.

1. I used Index controller instead of `MyModuleContoller`.
2. Alan Storm defined controller which is **not** under the **admin** module (i.e. adminhtml). When I use first config - it works perfect because I defined new modules under the section *adminhtml*. In Alan's config  I cannot add my module to adminhtml. I could override it but it is not correct because other modules under the adminhtml will be removed then.

This is correct code for menu under the `adminhtml`:

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mycompany_mymodule after="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</mycompany_mymodule >
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Inchoo also described this config [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/).